Dovecot IMAP mail fetch latency on import
We are working on importing emails from Gmail to Dovecot. During the process, all emails are written to a new directory within the mail folder. For fetching the emails, we are using the IMAP protocol with the imap_tools Python library.
After importing, we run the IMAP fetch at 5-second intervals. However, the newly imported emails do not appear immediately. They only become available after 30 to 40 seconds.
How can we resolve this issue? What steps can we take to debug and identify the source of the delay?

Are you writing files to the Maildir/ directory ? Dovecot relies on an index and transaction log file  to maintain the state of a mailbox and does not continuously scan the disk for changes in the Maildir/ directory structure , that happens only lazily . https://doc.dovecot.org/2.3/developer_manual/design/indexes/index_file_format/  and https://doc.dovecot.org/2.3/developer_manual/design/mailbox_syncing/ might be useful
